# How to Include a Directory Structure in Analytics Zoo

Tags: analytics-zoo

I want to execute a file on Analytics zoo but this file uses functions from other files in different subdirectories .

I am getting this error:

```
LogType:stdout LogLastModifiedTime:Tue Jun 15 06:43:07 -0500 2021 LogLength:157 LogContents: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from args import define_main_parser ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'args'

End of LogType:stdout
```

Here args.py is a separate file (I provided this file path in --py-files while spark file submission)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add your module to the PYTHONPATH environment variable using export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/your/modules on the driver node.

Comment: why is this a valid answer? please provide an explanation as to why this answer works.